# How to load time saved of a countdown when open a Jframe

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm development a countdown for a program, the time is saved successfully, but when i restart the program the label load the time but not resume. What do i need to make for resume the timer?

This is for a program that needs a software licence activation

```
private Timer t;
private int M = 5, S = 60;

File Save = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Countdown.txt");

private ActionListener accion = new ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {   

        S--;
        if( S == -1){
            M = M - 1;
            S = 60;
        }if( M == -1){
            M = 5;
            S = S - 0;
        }if( M == 1 && S == 1){
            Lbl_Warning.setText("Your'e Software Licence Soon Expire");
        }if( M == 0 && S == 1){
            Lbl_Warning.setText("Your'e Software Licence Expired");
            M = 0; S = 0;
            t.stop();
        }
        Update();
    }
};

public Crono() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    t = new Timer(1000, acciones);
    t.start();
}

public void Save(){
    try{
        if(!Save.exists()){
                Save.createNewFile();
        }{
        BufferedWriter BW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Save.getAbsolutePath()));
        BW.write(Lbl_Cronometro.getText());
        BW.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.getMessage();
    }
}

public void Charge(){
    try {
        if (Save.exists()){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(Save);

        Lbl_Crono.setText(sc.nextLine());
        sc.close();
        }
     } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
    }
}

private void Update() {
    String time = (M+" : "+S);
    Lbl_Crono.setText(time);
}

private void Lbl_ExitMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    if(t.isRunning()) 
    {
        t.stop();
        Save();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    Update();
}
```

I expect when I open again the JFrame, charge the saved time of the countdown and start.

Comment: 1) When do you read the value back in? 2) Don't calculate time this way.  A `Timer` is not accurate and guarantees only "at least" delay.  Better to use a `java.time.Instant` and calculate the difference between it and now

Comment: How Would You Do It?

Comment: Which part....?

Comment: How can i contact you?